# jquery run functions after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have four functions that include jQuery animations and stuff. I want them to run as soon as another finishes. I looked so many SO questions and answers, I have tried so many things (deferred, promise, callback, etc.), but no luck. Usually the result is whether they work simultaneously, or the second doesn't run. Any ideas how can I run them in order?

Here are my functions:

```
function hides(){
  $('#whiteLogo').hide('600');
  $('div.form').hide('600');
}

function moveTop(){
  $('nav').animate({
    'bottom': 'initial',
    'top': '0px'
  }, 600);
  $('.gradient').animate({
    'bottom': 'initial',
    'top': '-10px'
  }, 600);
}

function destroys(){
  $('.gradient').hide();
}

function content(){
  $('header').after('<section id=\'content\'>\t<div id=\'icons\'>\t</div>\t<section id=\'summary\'>\t\t\t</section>\t<section id=\'bulletin\'>\t\t</section></section>');
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I don't think it ha something to do with this, but as requested, here is my HTML:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href='#' class='linkPicture left'>
      <img src='../img/incnetWhite.png' alt='incnetWhite' id='headerLogo'>
    </a>
    <a href='../checkin/index.php' class='linkWord left' id='checkinLink'>
      Checkin
    </a>
    <a href='../weekend/index.php' class='linkWord left' id='weekendLink'>
      Weekend Departures
    </a>
    <a href='../etut/index.php' class='linkWord left' id='etutLink'>
      Etut Reservations
    </a>
    <div class='linkWord left more' id='moreLink'>
      More
      <img src='../img/header-drop.png' alt='drop' class='dropimg'>
      <div class='dropMenu more' id='moreMenu'>
        <a href='../pool/index.php' class='dropWord left' id='poolLink'>
          Pool Reservations
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='../admin/index.php' class='dropWord left' id='adminLink'>
          Admin Tools
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div href='#' class='linkWord right personal' id='personalLink'>
      Your Name 
      <img src='../img/header-drop.png' alt='drop' class='dropimg'>
      <div class='dropMenu personal' id='personalMenu'>
        <a href='../core/settings.php' class='dropWord left' id='settingLink'>
          Change Settings
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='../profiles/edit.php' class='dropWord left' id='profileLink'>
          Profile Settings
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='../core/hiring.php' class='dropWord left' id='hiringLink'>
          Apply to INÇNET
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='../core/about.php' class='dropWord left' id='aboutLink'>
          About Us
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href='../core/logoff.php' class='dropWord left' id='logoffLink'>
          Sign Out
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>   
<div class='form'>
    <form method='POST'>
        <span id='welcome'>Welcome!</span>
        <!--<label class='fieldname' id='username'>Username:</label>-->
        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username' size='10'>
        <br>
        <!--<label class='fieldname' id='password'>Password:</label>-->
        <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;' size='10'>
        <br>
        <span id='remember'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='remember'>
            <label class='fildname' id='rememberme'>Remember Me</label>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span id='error'>
        </span>
        <input type='submit' name='signin' value='Sign In' id='signin'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try using the [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: If possible, can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: @Mottie I tried `queue()` too, maybe because I did something wrong but I couldnt make it work.

Comment: Totally hokey suggestion, and I hesitate even to suggest it, but perhaps a series of setTimeouts? I've had to do it myself in the past...

Comment: @gibberish I don't want to use timeouts. Its hell of a work and really hard to maintain.

Comment: [Take a look at this post](http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/10/managing-multiple-animation-sequences_6039.html) -- about half-way down the page: "Using that same approach with the example I developed in this post:"

Comment: @gibberish As I unedrstand, it creates a chain of callbacks, but I couldnt make it work. They still work at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can tell, you want to perform events against multiple elements in sequence. With a little bit of playing around we can leverage jQuery's Deferred's and make a solution **[(view JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ng75bu1x/)** such as:

```
function runDeferred() {
    var args = arguments;
    if(args.length) {
        var next = Array.prototype.shift.call(args);
        $.when(next()).done(function() {
            runDeferred.apply(this, args);
        });
    }
```

This method can takes a list of methods, and calls them consecutively. The methods themselves need to return the a jQuery object of the elements that we wish to wait for. Here's an example of such a method:

```
function fadeBar() {
    return $("#bar").fadeIn(1000).animate({
        "font-size": "2em"
    }, 1000);
}
```

And here's how you can combine them:

```
runDeferred(fadeFoo, fadeBar, fadeZulu);
```

Comment: It seems like your method works (as i look at jsfiddle), but I need some more info to adapt this method to my example. What does `runDeferred.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));` mean?

Comment: It means pull off the next method from the list and repeat the process.

Comment: A question, in some of my functions, I have more than one animation. Which one would I return? Does that matter?

Comment: @BarışDEMİREL so I was looking at that, you should just return `$('#whiteLog, div.form').hide('600');` and in general, you could probably just do `return $(a).add(b);` and so forth

Comment: What if the animations are different, as in `moveTop()` in my example?

Comment: Use add to group all the elements into a jQuery object and return that

Comment: What do you mean, I have no idea about it. How can I do that?

Comment: In your moveTop method you would add an extra line `return $("nav, .gradient").promise() ` or `return $("nav").add(".gradient").promise() `

Comment: Yes, after I applied all said, it works. Thank you very much for solving this big problem for me. If I had enough rep. I'd upvote but since I don't I just can accept the answer, perfect!

Comment: @IanClark see http://jsfiddle.net/qht6rk4f/1/ Same thing can be achieved by using $.when().done without using promise() at the end of each function. Is there any benefit to using promise() instead of $.when()?

Comment: @BarışDEMİREL no problem :) - I upvoted your question as it wasn't actually a silly one - however I strongly suggest you read ["how to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which will help yours gain attention! In particular, your question included way to much code and wasn't scoped enough. That said, welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: @artm whilst it doesn't look mandatory in this situation, having the methods which you want to call return Promises makes the intentions clearer IMO. Good spot though :)

Comment: @artm actually updated to be simpler and also use your approach, TY :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into method chaining. That's worked for me in the past.

http://schier.co/post/method-chaining-in-javascript

Comment: This will work with a single jQuery Object set, but the OP wants to use multiple by the looks of things

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Utilizing [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) , as suggested by Mottie

```
   function hides(){
      $('#whiteLogo').hide(600);
        $('div.form').hide(600, d);
    };

    function moveTop() {
      $('nav').animate({
        'bottom': 'initial',
        'top': '0px'
      }, 600);
      $('.gradient').animate({
        'bottom': 'initial',
        'top': '-10px'
      }, 600, d);

    };

    function destroys() {
        $('.gradient').hide(600, d);

    };

    function content() {
        $('header').after('<section style=background:blue id=\'content\'>'
        + '\t<div id=\'icons\'>\t</div>\t<section id=\'summary\'>'
        + '\t\t\t</section>\t<section id=\'bulletin\'>'
        + '\t\t</section>section</section>');
    };

$("body").queue("animations", [hides, moveTop, destroys, content]);
var d = function() {
  return $("body").dequeue("animations")
};
hides()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/0Lx4t54y/

Comment: No, this doesnt work. If you add background color to the section added by jquery, you can understand that they dont work by order.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks should work. I'm not exactly sure what it is that you're trying to do, but it seems like you're saying you want one to run after another.

```
function hides(callback){
  $('#whiteLogo').hide('600', function(){
    $('div.form').hide('600', function(){
        if (callback){
            callback();
        }
    });
  });

}

function moveTop(callback){
  $('nav').animate({
    'bottom': 'initial',
    'top': '0px'
  }, 600, function(){
      $('.gradient').animate({
        'bottom': 'initial',
        'top': '-10px'
      }, 600, function(){
          if (callback){
              callback();
          }
      });
  });

}

function destroys(callback){
  $('.gradient').hide(function(){
      if (callback){
          callback();
      }
  });
}


//I have never used after but I'm sure it's similar to the callback structure above.
function content(){
  $('header').after('<section id=\'content\'>\t<div id=\'icons\'>\t</div>\t<section id=\'summary\'>\t\t\t</section>\t<section id=\'bulletin\'>\t\t</section></section>');
}
```

Callbacks can be used like this.

```
hides(function(){
   doSomething();
});
```

Comment: When I tried callbacks, I needed to create a chain of callbacks and that give an error. All the functions at the same time, actually.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You want all the functions to fire at the same time?

Comment: No, I dont. but what you advice does that. When I apply that solution, all of the functions work at the same time.

Comment: Please tell me what order you want the jquery functions (not the functions in which they are housed) to fire, and which ones can be fired at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share information on how you call the functions. All the animation functions on jQuery has callbacks on complete. To call other function at the moment the animation is complete you can use the following code.

```
function hides(){
    $('#whiteLogo').hide(600);
    $('div.form').hide(600, moveTop);
}

function moveTop(){
    $('nav').animate({
        'bottom': 'initial',
        'top': '0px'
    }, 600);
    $('.gradient').animate({
        'bottom': 'initial',
        'top': '-10px'
    }, 600, destroys);
}

function destroys(){
    $('.gradient').hide(600, content);
}

function content(){
    $('header').after('<section id=\'content\'>\t<div id=\'icons\'>\t</div>\t<section id=\'summary\'>\t\t\t</section>\t<section id=\'bulletin\'>\t\t</section></section>');
}
```

This way when you call hide() you'll have a chain of callback one after other. As you can see I only check one of the animations per function because they are limited to the same execution time (Ex. hides() has 2 animations of 600ms, so I assume that if one has finished, the other should have been as well).

Be advised that this piece of code could be refactored in an event driven pattern and if you ask me - think of some kind of better design pattern.

Check jQuery's documentation as well http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: This doesnt work. I tried exactly the same, but they all work at the same time.

Comment: Well, remove the quotes from the intervals in the hide() function. I'll edit my code. I wrote a simple script to show you the error http://jsfiddle.net/5g4ssjo3/2/

Comment: I removed but no way.

Comment: I think you expect something different from the hide function. It's the same as you've called .slideUp() and after that the moveTop() function is not doing anything. Please review your animations.

Comment: I know what they do. `hides()` sets display value to none and animates. `moveTop`moves a fixed element at bottom to top. `destroys()` hides an element that moved to outside of viewport. `content()` adds some content to page. `content()` should work after all the other but with your solution, it works at the same time with others and it blocks the other animations. That's why this doesn't work, sorry, but not a good answer.